# Openlayers2 snapping the whole feature

Tags: openlayers-2, snapping

Is it possible to snap (drag and snap) a feature to another feature in the same layer?

I found `OpenLayers.Control.Snapping` module but it's snapping only to the points.

Answer (score 1):

The OpenLayers snapping controls will snap to points and nodes in a line/polygon. It will even snap to 'pseudo nodes' like the intersections between lines. See this example for more - [OpenLayers Snapping and Splitting](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/snap-split.html).

If what you are actually after (and if it is I would recommend making your question clearer) is moving a whole polygon/line as one (i.e. not node by node) until it snapped with another feature then I am afraid I am not sure. I am highly doubtful and I've certainly never come across anything like that. Someone else may be able to shed some mroe light though.

Comment: I agree with you, the only tools that I know that can snaps many nodes at a time are the ArcGIS 10.x topology tools such the edges to topology snapper.

Comment: You mentioning topology has suddenly made me remember the JavaScript Topology Suite. This might have something in it? I have not ever looked at it myself though so you're on your own! https://github.com/bjornharrtell/jsts

Comment: if you can create a tool that snaps entire polygon with JTS, you are really great! It is possible, but no one have done it in the Open community for now.

Comment: Yes, I would like to move a whole polygon as one and snap it to another polygon (edge to edge).